# Notification when visible area of CALayer changes?

Tags: ios, macos, core-animation

I have a CALayer for which I provide content for only the visible area (somewhat similar to CATiledLayer). The problem is there does not seem to be a way to receive notification when the visible area of the CALayer changes so that displayLayer is called. I currently subclass and hook setPosition, setBounds, and setTransform, but this doesn't catch the cases where a superview/layer changes (for example, UIScrollView scrolls by changing the scroll views origin ). I'm left hooking parent views and sprinkling setNeedsDisplay all over the code.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

The currently visible rect is `[CALayer visibleRect]`. This is set by the scroll view (layer) and is what you're expected to base drawing on in scroll views.

You probably want to override `-needsDisplayOnBoundsChange` to return `YES`. That's typically how you handle most of what you're describing.

If you want things like position to force a redraw (that's unusual, but possible), then you can override `+needsDisplayForKey:` to return `YES` for any key changes that you want to force a redraw.

If you want to make sure you're only drawing what you need to draw, then you should be checking your clipping box using `CGContextGetClipBoundingBox()` during your drawing code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. visbleRect is a readonly property, so doesn't provide notification. needsDisplayOnBoundsChange only catches to my layer bounds, not any changes in the stack of views/layers containing my layer. Similarly, setNeedsDisplayForKey only catches changes to my layer (though it may be a better solution than overriding the methods as I currently do). CGContextGetClipBoundingBox() is of no use because I don't have a CGContext.  I'm setting the layer content directly with an image that is not rendered by CG. Still no general solution.